# How to change the background color of searchview

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

my searchview by default has got black background color, like below. i want the background color to be white.

[image]

I tried like this, but no luck :(. No changes in color as i observe :(

```
 -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
    </style>



     <style name="SearchViewStyle" 
       parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/RED</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/WHITE</item>

</style>
```